# Developing Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync client

Tags: client, exchange-server, activesync

Does anybody know if there are any licensing limitations on developing Exchange ActiveSync client? (like there in the Android/iPhone devices).

We would like to sync Hotmail accounts and ActiveSync sounds like a good way.
I know there is an [Exchange ActiveSync Logo Program](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/gg187968) but i'm not sure whether it's needed for developing a ActiveSync server, client or both.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you're developing an EAS client, server or both - Microsoft [requires a license](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/intellectualproperty/iplicensing/programs/exchangeactivesyncprotocol.aspx) for any implementation of the protocol. You need to contact their IP lawyers to get a license agreement in place.